# Salesforce - Commcare integration

Tags: rest-api, integration, schedulebatch

i am trying to integrate Commcare to Salesforce. Commcare provides its own rest api. From Salesforce, I need to call this api and upsert data into salesforce.

Current approach is a scheduled apex class. There would be only 1 call and all data would be fetched in only 1 call and then processed & upserted. The disadvantage of this would be when the data becomes large gradually, it would break heap limit.

The rest api also takes a offset parameter so that we can fetch data in chunks.But there is a limit of 100 callouts in apex transaction. If the chunks exceed 100 then there will be problem. Do you think we can use the batch class in this case ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks